# My dropdown is not working using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I create a dropdown which is the drop down will be triggered by a button from the search bar and underneath the search bar the drop down content will be deploy. Though my code wont work

```html
<div class="col-8">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend" id="button-addon3">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" style="color:black;background-color: darkcyan">Search</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#about">About</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" style="color:black;background-color: darkcyan" onCLick="myFunction()">Filter</button>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Reports Here" aria-label="Example text with two button addons" aria-describedby="button-addon3">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that triggers the dropdown? I just see HTML, no JS where an event listener is doing the work.

Comment: Please go through bootstrap documents again. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/dropdowns/. you miss many classes and attributes in the code

Comment: I already have libraries and I do have already the links that is needed. That is working but the content won't show up.

Comment: That is just a fragment of my code and sorry if I did not include everything.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are using bootstrap you can make use of bootstrap dropdown itself please kindly use the below code no need of writing script as well in this. :)

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Filter</button>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not working. My design has kind a twist on it.